# Different levels of logging with log4net

Tags: log4net, appender, log-level

I must log some methods. In one method I must log everything. In all others method I've just log exception...
I have done this configuration:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="OneMethodFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    ...

    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="realMethod" />
      <stringToMatch value="xxx" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <appender name="WebsiteFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    ...

    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="realMethod" />
      <stringToMatch value="xxx" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="WebsiteFileAppender">
      <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </appender-ref>
    <appender-ref ref="OneMethodFileAppender">
      <threshold value="INFO" />
    </appender-ref>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

So, when I match the property `realMethod` I should use the appender `OneMethodFileAppender` that log at the INFO level; in all other cases i should use the appender `WebsiteFileAppender` that log at ERROR level.

I have a different output. 
1. When i match the method `xxx` everything works correctly. I mean that a log at INFO level in the correct log.
2. But when I do not match the method `xxx`, I log in both files and both at INFO level.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the logger element to configure your logging:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="OneMethodFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
  </appender>

  <appender name="WebsiteFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
  </appender>

  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="WebsiteFileAppender">
      <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </appender-ref>
  </root>
  <logger name="LoggerName1">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="WebsiteFileAppender" />
   </logger>
   <logger name="LoggerName2">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="OneMethodFileAppender" />
   </logger>
</log4net>
```

Both methods should have there own logger:

```
logger = LogManager.GetLogger("logger1");
```